# returning an array from a method that is being called from a txt file

Tags: java, arrays, return

I am trying to return an array that is being read from a txt file. and calling it into another method to use the data in an equation. This is in java, and I am new to java, so don't yell at me for not knowing all of the tricks. here is part of my coding

```
public static void getdata(double [] Gravity) throws IOException
{

  File fileName = new File("gravity1.txt");
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
  while (inFile.hasNext())
  {
    for (int val = 0; val<9; val++)
    {
      Gravity[val] = inFile.nextDouble();
    }
    inFile.close();
  }

}
```

this is calling the data from the txt file. and I need to use it in this method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      double pounds = 187.8;
      double mass= convertpoundstokg(pounds);
      double[] gravity = {0.0};
      gravity=  getdata();

      double[] weight= {0.0};
      for (int val=0; val<8; val++)
      {
        weight[val]=  mass * Gravity[val];
      }
    }
```

Comment: `while(inFile.hasNext())` should be `while(inFile.hasNextDouble())`.

Comment: `mass * Gravity[val]` should be `mass * gravity[val]`

Comment: @orangegoat No, he is population the array passed as parameter.

Comment: Thanks i did not see that

Comment: I tried adding a return but I still get an error I get cannot return a value from method whose result type is void. If I remove void from the method I then get the error invalid method declaration; return type is required and when i input the return type it then says incompatible types and then when I change it to double [] then I get method get data in class WeightsOnPlanetsV1 cannot be applied to given types it says required double[] found: no arguments; reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length.

Comment: `gravity = getdata();` should be `getdata(gravity);` in the main function.

Comment: Either use a dynamically sized collection (such as an ArrayList) if you don't know how many elements you have, or set the size of the parameter you pass. You're passing an array with a single array but attempting to set elements > 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
public static void getdata(double [] Gravity) throws IOException
```

to:

```
public static double[] getdata() throws IOException
```

and follow the advice given in the comments to your question.